# Get number of specific weekdays between dates

Tags: mysql

How to get the amount of a specific weekday from a date range, without loops?

- start_date = 2020-01-01
- end_date = 2020-01-24
- weekday = 3 (wednesday)

Get the amount of wednesdays between these dates.

```
WEEKDAYS_COUNT(startdate, enddate, weekday)
```

If the date range has the same start and enddate, it should output 1, if this date is a wednesday.

Note: This isn't a duplicate.
No-one has a working formula for this question, other than excluding saturday and sundays.

Answer (score 0):

I'd query a `calendar` table of all possible dates. e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE cal (dt DATE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (dt)) ;
```

populated with all of the dates between the two dates we are checking,

```
INSERT INTO cal (dt) VALUES ('2019-01-01'),('2019-01-02'),('2019-01-03'),...
```

There are other ways to generate a set of rows, without invoking a static pre-built calendar table. We just need enough rows, and way to generate distinct date values between the two boundaries. Other databases have some nifty ways of generating a sequence of integers; we can get MySQL to generate a finite boatload of rows with some messy UNION ALL and CROSS JOIN operations)

However we generate the rows, the approach is the same:

Conditional aggregation. We can get a set of date values between the two boundaries.  Determine whether that date is considered a wednesday or not, and return a 1 or 0 respectively. Collapse all the rows into a single row, and total up the 1s and 0s to get a count.

Something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(WEEKDAY(c.dt)+1 = 3 ,1,0)) AS cnt_wednesdays
  FROM cal c
 WHERE c.dt >= '2020-01-01' + INTERVAL 0 DAY
   AND c.dt  < '2020-01-24' + INTERVAL 0 DAY
```

Notes:

MySQL WEEKDAY() function 0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, ... 6 = Sunday

MySQL DAYOFWEEK() function: 1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, ... 7 = Saturday

Should the lower and/or upper boundary dates be considered as an included  "wednesday" if they fall on a wednesday?

For example, consider the range from  Wednesday Jan 2 '2019-01-02' to Wednesday Jan 9 '2019-01-09'; do we want to return a "wednesday" count of 0, 1 or 2 ?

Adjust the equality included/excluded from comparison operators `>` / `>=` and `<` / `<=` as appropriate to include/exclude the boundary dates.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate amount of a specific weekday from a date range in MySQL (with a little change it will work in other SQL engines)

depend on WEEKDAY number per each weekday:

```
0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, 2 = Wednesday, 3 = Thursday, 4 = Friday, 5 = Saturday, 6 = Sunday
```

if you would like calculate for Wednesday then you should using 2 for conditions:

```
select @wday:=WEEKDAY(start_date), @difday:=datediff(end_date, start_date), 
(CASE
    WHEN start_date > end_date THEN 0
    WHEN start_date = end_date THEN 1
    ELSE 
    CASE 
        WHEN @wday>2 THEN ( @difday div 7 ) + IF( (@difday mod 7) - (7-@wday)>=2,1,0 )
        WHEN @wday<2 THEN ( @difday div 7 ) + IF( (@difday mod 7) >= (2-@wday),1,0 )
        WHEN @wday=2 THEN ( @difday div 7 )
    END

END) as WEEKDAYS from table1
```